# Stop Nepali Text from changing when pasted into a Word 365 document

Tags: ms-word, office365

I work for a translation company and we need to enter some Nepali text into a word document. We found that when entered, some of the text is being changed by Word. We also found that this is only happening on the desktop version of Word and not the online version.

The specific text that is being changed is:
जाेडेपछि

I tried copying what it changes into and pasting it here as well, but doing so changes it back. I've attached a screenshot of how the text ends up appearing.

[Text pasted into Word for desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9k164.png)

Text should not change when pasted into Word. We found that if we use Word in a browser it does not change, but when the document is saved and opened in Word for desktop it changes.